# Use scope on all measures in OLAP cube except one or more selected calculated measures

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, cube, olap-cube

I created a scope that makes time calculations. The problem is that I need these calculations to be calculated for most measures and do nothing for some special measures. I know the measures that I want to throw out of scope (for example `[Measures].[Stock Unit Close]`). In addition, this measure is calculated.
I try to use

`scope(EXCEPT([Measures].allmembers, [Measures].[Stock Unit Close]));
...;
end scope;`

but it doesn't work. It ends with this error

> A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members.
>   MdxScript(Core) (1510, 2) A set has been encountered that cannot contain calculated members.
>   The END SCOPE statement does not match the opening SCOPE statement.
>   MdxScript(Core) (1568, 1) The END SCOPE statement does not match the opening SCOPE statement.
>   One or more errors were encountered in the MDX script.

and in addition this code work only on natural measures but does not work on calculated measures.

Can anyone helps me please?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not exactly what you want, because you have to SCOPE all measure groups separately. But at least not each measure.

This works for both natural and calculated measures from measure group.

E.g. measure group name is "Activations", exclude one measure from SCOPE.

```
scope(MeasureGroupMeasures("Activations")-[Measures].[Average Activation Amount]);
this=1;
end scope;
```

or

```
scope(EXCEPT(MeasureGroupMeasures("Activations"),[Measures].[Client Accommodation Amount]));
this=1;
end scope;
```

Comment: Yes I think, that this is the only option that works at least partially.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the word `SCOPE` and do what you want:

```
(EXCEPT([Measures].allmembers, [Measures].[Stock Unit Close])) = 123;
```

This trick is a bit of a hidden way to scope on both physical and calculated measures at once.